# about AccessibilityService network request error on android

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

Firstly, my English is not good.If there are any grammar errors, please forgive me. When developing the AccessibilityService project, there is a requirement to request the interface on my server on onAccessibilityEvent(). At the beginning, running the AccessibilityService project can make network requests in onAccessibilityEvent, but once Android is restarted, it will report an error

I don't understand why this error was reported

error info:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9s49.png)

my code:

```
public class HongBaoService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String ACTION_HIDE="com.example.accessibilityt.ACTION_HIDE";
    private SideBarHideReceiver mReceiver;
    private SideBarArrow mLeftArrowBar;
    public static HongBaoService mService;

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d("InitApp","AccessibilityService_connected");
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"onServiceConnected");
        mService=this;
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter("com.example.accessibilityt.XposedReceiver.ACTION_AGAIN");
        registerReceiver(responseXposed,intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createToucher();
    }

    @SuppressLint({"RtlHardcoded", "InflateParams"})
    private void createToucher() {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"AccessibilityService onCreate");
        Log.d("InitApp","AccessibilityService_create");
        // get window manager
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        // left arrow
        mLeftArrowBar = new SideBarArrow();
        LinearLayout mArrowLeft = mLeftArrowBar.getView(this, windowManager, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d("InitApp","AccessibilityService_event");
**# //the key**
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
                Request request=new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://192.168.169.1:8088/dex2java/test")
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.d("InitAppA",response.body().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }.start();
        if (sendRequestThead==null)
            sendRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d("InitApp","onInterrupt");
        mService=null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mLeftArrowBar.clearAll();
        unregisterReceiver(responseXposed);
        mService=null;
    }
    public static boolean isStart(){
        return mService!=null;
    }
    public Queue<XposedRequestData> queue=new LinkedList<>();
    private BroadcastReceiver responseXposed=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String urlPath=intent.getStringExtra("urlPath");
            String fileName=intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
            String packageName=intent.getStringExtra("packageName");
            String apkPath=intent.getStringExtra("apkPath");
            Log.i("InitApp",urlPath+" "+fileName+" "+packageName+" "+apkPath);
            queue.add(new XposedRequestData(urlPath,fileName,packageName,apkPath));
            loopSetViewProvider(urlPath,fileName,packageName);
        }
    };

    private static volatile boolean isInterrupt=false;
    private static volatile boolean isOnDestroy=false;
    private void loopSetViewProvider(String urlPath,String fileName,String packageName){
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    if (isInterrupt)
                        break;
                }
                if (queue==null||queue.size()<=0)
                    return;
                InputStream inputStream;
                XposedRequestData data;
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer;
                try {
                    data=queue.poll();
                    buffer=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    inputStream=getApkFile(data.apkPath,data.fileName);
                    int bytesRead;
                    byte[] arrayByte=new byte[4096];
                    while ((bytesRead=inputStream.read(arrayByte,0,arrayByte.length))!=-1){
                        buffer.write(arrayByte,0,bytesRead);
                    }
                    buffer.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                if (inputStream==null){
                    Log.d("InitAppA","inputstream is null");
                    return;
                }
                Log.i("InitAppA",urlPath+" "+fileName+" "+packageName+" "+buffer.toByteArray());
//                VDataTools.extraDoPost(urlPath,fileName,packageName,inputStream,"second");
**# The fact is that I want to make a network request here, and there are two triggering conditions for this thread. One is the onAccessibilityEvent call, and the other is responseXposed receiving the request**

            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    private ZipFile zipFile;
    private InputStream getApkFile(String apkPath, String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file=new File(apkPath);
        if (file==null||apkPath==null)
            return null;
        zipFile=new ZipFile(file);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()){
            ZipEntry entry=entries.nextElement();
            String entryName=entry.getName();
            if (entryName.equals(fileName)){
                Log.d("InitAppA",entryName+"   "+fileName);
                return zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            }
        }
        zipFile.close();
        return null;
    }
    private Thread sendRequestThead;
    private void sendRequest(){
        sendRequestThead=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!isOnDestroy){
                    try {
                        if (isInterrupt)
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        isInterrupt=!isInterrupt;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        sendRequestThead.start();
    }
    private class XposedRequestData{
        public String urlPath;
        public String fileName;
        public String packageName;
        public String apkPath;
        public XposedRequestData(String urlPath,String fileName,String packageName,String apkPath){
            this.urlPath=urlPath;
            this.fileName=fileName;
            this.packageName=packageName;
            this.apkPath=apkPath;
        }
    }
}
```